# Count character from a varchar column in json format

Tags: mysql, sql, json, string, count

MYSQL - It will be my last post. I have a customer table that has a varchar (string) column. It is a json in string format.

I need to count the amount of characters for each field in the string. example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|  table client                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | name (type string)                               |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | {"name":"Dylan Smith","valor":"$ 210,02"}        |
| 2  | {"name":"Bruce Johnson","valor":"$ 1.210,02"}    |
| 3  | {"name":"James Williams","valor":"$ 50.210,02"}  |
| 4  | {"name":"Jimmy Jones","valor":"$ 87.210,02"}     |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I need a query that returns me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|  resulta                                              |
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | qtd_name_caracter | qtd_value_caracter           |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   11              |     8                        |
| 2  |   13              |     10                       |
| 3  |   14              |     11                       |
| 4  |   11              |     11                       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea how to do this query. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why your column type is `varchar` if you are saving a json? Instead, consider it changing to `JSON` in which case @GMB's solution is perfect.

Comment: @Raghav is a legacy system. It has been in production for a few years now. I tested GMB solution here and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If these strings are consistently properly formatted JSON, then you can use JSON functions on them:

```
select id,
    char_length(name ->> '$.name' ) qtd_name_character,
    char_length(name ->> '$.value') qtd_value_character
from mytable
```

Comment: I think OP said the column `name` is of type `varchar`.

Comment: @GMB you saved my life! that's what I needed!

Comment: @RaghavGarg: yes. MySQL wil do implicit conversion.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that. Thanks for sharing.